# Variation of action for Jackiw-Teitelboim (JT) gravity in order to get equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

Im having a bit of trouble understanding the variation of action for JT gravity (for example in this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01857 the equation 3.8).

I dont really get how do they get from 3.8 to 3.9. Every time a try to vary the action I arrive at expressions with ricci scalar.

The action has the form of (3.8):

[image]

and the equation of motion I should be  gettin is:

[image]

I think i need to express the scalar curvature as the function of the metric and its first (or second) derivatives, but I cant figure out (or find out) how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing a draft for an article on JT gravity,  but I have been advised to take on a project with a professor instead which is what I am doing. I think I learned how to do this while working on my draft. So maybe I will share that.

\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{16 \pi G_N} \int d^2 x \sqrt{-g} \phi (R + 2 \Lambda) 
\end{equation}

Let's vary this with respect to $\phi$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} -  \partial_\mu \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \partial_{\mu} \phi} = 0
\end{equation}
It should be obvious that the equation one gets from this is:
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{-g}( R + 2 \Lambda)  = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 R = - 2 \Lambda 
\end{equation}
This is just a statement about the curvature of the space.

The trickier yet still doable variation is the variation with respect to the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$. The easiest way to do this is to look up Appendix E of Robert M. Wald's text on general relativity. These rules have been taken from there although they were first brought to my attention from notes of  Physics 8.962 of MIT by Edmund Bertschinger. Here are the rules reproduced here:

\begin{align*}
\delta \sqrt{-g} &= -\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}, \\
\delta \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu} &= -\frac{1}{2} h \nabla_{\mu}(g^{\nu\lambda} \delta g_{\alpha\lambda}) + \nabla_{\nu}(g^{\mu\lambda} \delta g_{\alpha\lambda}) - \nabla_{\beta}(g^{\mu\kappa} g^{\nu\lambda} g_{\alpha\beta} \delta g_{\kappa\lambda}), \\
\delta R_{\mu\nu} &= \nabla_{\alpha} (\delta \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}) - \nabla_{\mu} (\delta \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\alpha\nu}), \\
g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu} &= \nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu} (-\delta g^{\mu\nu} + g^{\mu\nu} g^{\alpha\beta} \delta g_{\alpha\beta}), \\
\delta(g^{\mu\nu} R_{\mu\nu} \sqrt{-g}) &= (G^{\mu\nu} \delta g_{\mu\nu} + g^{\mu\nu} \delta R_{\mu\nu}) \sqrt{-g}.
\end{align*}

All we do now is look for the terms and do the substitution. One can write the variation of the action specifically noticing that it looks like the Einstein-Hilbert action but for the dilaton. I confirmed this by looking at David Tong's notes on general relativity.

\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int d^2 x \phi[ (\delta \sqrt{-g} g^{\mu \nu } R_{\mu \nu} + \sqrt{-g}(\delta g^{\mu \nu}  R_{\mu \nu} + \sqrt{-g}g^{\mu \nu}\delta R_{\mu \nu} - 2 \delta \sqrt{-g}]
\end{equation}

At this point, we just substitute in from the rules.

\begin{equation}
\delta S = \int d^2 x \phi[ (\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} g^{\mu \nu } R_{\mu \nu} + \sqrt{-g}(\delta g^{\mu \nu}  R_{\mu \nu} + \sqrt{-g}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu} (-\delta g^{\mu\nu} + g^{\mu\nu} g^{\alpha\beta} \delta g_{\alpha\beta}) - 2 \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-g} g_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu}]
\end{equation}

If all is right, one might get:

\begin{equation}
T_{\mu \nu}\phi= \nabla_\mu \nabla_\nu \phi - g_{\mu\nu} \nabla^2 \phi + g_{\mu\nu} \phi
\end{equation}

Maybe someone with more experience can look over my answer.

Comment: How do you get the terms where the covariant derivatives act on the dilaton field? I just get something that looks like einsteins field equations from the variation w.r.t. the metric.